# The AES encryption in php and C use openssl library

Tags: php, c, encryption, openssl, aes

I want to encrypt some fix length (512bytes) data by AES encryption algorithm in PHP and later decrypt it in C.

The PHP code looks like below.

```
$plaintext = "...";     // 512bytes.
$iv = "...";            // 128bits long;
$password = "...";      // 128bits long;

$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt ($plaintext, 'aes-256-cbc', $password, true, $iv);
```

Then, I write the cipher text in a file, in turn open it by a C program whose source code looks same as the one on [this page](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#Encrypting_the_message).

But, luckily, it doesn't working. The output of the C program is something unreadable.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong, and is there an alternative way to fulfil this mission?

---

UPDATES:
  The full PHP code here:

```
<?php
    $string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
    $pass = '01234567890123456789012345678901';
    $iv = 'NiceToMeetYou^-^';
    $method = 'aes-256-cbc';
    file_put_contents ('./file.encrypted', openssl_encrypt ($string, $method, $pass, TRUE, $iv));
?>
```

The C code is totally same as [this page](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#Encrypting_the_message), except the iv which is changed to *NiceToMeetYou^-^*.

The PHP's output is

```
00000000  11 58 bf 4e 1c f7 ff f5  56 dc 9b 01 32 fe 16 66  |.X.N....V...2..f|
00000010  4b aa 0f ca e1 b7 a8 5f  c8 64 83 bf d6 88 02 59  |K......_.d.....Y|
00000020  26 0a 62 00 27 2d 78 b4  70 82 d4 9a ac bf 1b c7  |&.b.'-x.p.......|
```

The file generated by C program is:

```
0000 - 67 95 70 57 7d d4 52 49-fc 5d 2a 06 3d 66 ef 21   g.pW}.RI.]*.=f.!
0010 - 57 0d e0 cf aa b9 c0 71-b5 ad 0e 0b 56 26 6b 2e   W......q....V&k.
0020 - aa 99 4f 47 2e 6e 08 d7-ec f1 bf a0 8e f3 0d 0a   ..OG.n..........
```

Comment: Why do you set your `options` parameter to `true`? Please use one of the constants defined for it. Oh sorry, stupid IF spec, that means raw (bytes) output. I'm afraid that *looks the same* doesn't cut it, please show source and input / output in hex.

Comment: I have pasted the both output and the php source code. The C code is very same as [link](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#Encrypting_the_message), except that I modified the iv to _NiceToMeetYou^-^_

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your C input or PHP output method, that plaintext seems to end with `0d 0a` and without a padding error (I presume here you do error checking). This probably means that something's got mangled in the process. The crypto itself seems to match...

Comment: I think the reason that why the outputs are different is padding. It seems that the padding in PHP and C is different. But I am just guessing. By now, I have not yet correct it.

Comment: It's unlikely to be different for the `openssl` ciphers in PHP, just the `mcrypt` ones.